# Count students per gender per course schedule

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a macro that counts the number of Male/Female students in a class per scheduled time and then put the results in a separate sheet.
Here is the sample data and the result that I would like to see:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please note that SO is not a code writing service, you need to make your own attempt first then ask a question here (with your code attempt) and explain what's not working in order for us to help you.

Comment: With that said, you should be able to achieve this by using PivotTable. Have you tried that?

Comment: Try by using countifs() probably easier than vba.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments said, using COUNTIFS formula here seems like the simplest solution. In the count column you can enter a dynamic formula and then copy it down. You need to enter the COUNTIFS formula with the appropriate lookup references for course, gender and time from the output table, and the correct correlating ranges in the list table to build your multiple critera.

```
=COUNTIFS(range1, criteria1, range2, criteria2, [...])
```

Referring to the columns in the list table as A to D, then those in the output as E to H, *and treating the layout exactly like the screenshot, assuming the output table is 2 rows below and to the right of the list table as the picture) the following example should help - (This example would go in H4, then copy down and the dynamic values should change automatically).

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B, $H4, C:C, $E4, D:D, $F4)
```

This will then count the number of instances where Gender, Course and Time in the list table match the 3 values in the row in the output table.

If you wanted to 'hardcode' the criteria then you need to put text criteria in quotes, such as

B:B, "M"
or

C:C, "Physics 101"

If you want this in a separate sheet then either put the COUNTIFS with fully qualified references i.e. SHEETNAME!C:C, SHEETNAME!$E4, or just refer to the count values in the output table by direct cell reference cell in the 'other' sheet. No need to save as macro enabled sheet then either.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew!